# SQL record insertion without query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

Ok, this is definitely weird. I have a cakephp app I'm using. I've removed all code from the `controller action`, `view`, `beforeFilter`. I even did a sql dump to see what queries were being made to the database. And even though there were no queries being made to the database, a record keeps getting inserted in one of my tables. How is this possible?

Comment: You execute a query at some point. Check the scripts you haven't checked yet then double-check everything.

Comment: I found out where it's happening, but can't figure out why.

Comment: @LordZardeck It appears your initial question was answered, and you have updated this question to include a second question.  If I am correct, please remove the second question from here, and address it in a new question.  This will help you by removing clutter from the discussion of your original question, as well as providing others a clear problem to look at solving.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But since no one ever gave the correct answer for this question, should I delete it?

Comment: @LordZardeck If you answered your own question, you can post that answer, along with how you found it, if relevant, and accept it.

Comment: I hate to accept my own answer, but I went ahead and did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the problem. I had two routes that matched the address. So 2 requests where executed.

```
Router::connect('/profile/settings', array('controller' => 'players', 'action' => 'settings'));
Router::connect('/profile/*', array('controller' => 'players', 'action' => 'view'));
```

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html

Turn on general query log and find query inside it.